# Kuwait visa cancelation

Tags: visas

Last October 2017, I was hired by one of the biggest company in Kuwait. They sent a formal job offer after a week and I've waited for my working visa for 2-3 months.

Unfortunately, they cannot process my working visa because I have an existing valid visa at that time, which was approved last November 2017, and expired dated Feb. 2018. According to my employer, the company who applied for such a visa under my name should be the only people authorized to cancel this expired visa in Kuwait immigration.

For the record, it's supposedly my first time to work in kuwait next to KSA. And honestly, I don't have any pending or on going applications in kuwait. I'm just wondering how could it happen and I'm afraid that somebody used or hacked my credentials for illegal use.

Comment: So you're saying this current visa was not applied for by you, you had no knowledge of it until now?